kubernetes ingress controller how to configure api to api mapping
How to do the nginx configuration below in ingress controller
location /check_result {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7764/check_result;

I've the below configuration
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: check_result-ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /check_result
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: check_result-ip-service
            port:
              number: 7764


but how to redirect it to the check_result path on the check_result-ip-service service

Try the below ingress rule
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: check_result-ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /check_result$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /check_result(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: check_result-ip-service
            port:
              number: 7764

